# Groovyc *.groovy strange behavior

Tags: java, groovy, compilation, groovyc

I have a handfull of groovy files that I compile into java class files with groovyc (because it's a good bit quicker to start java than starting up groovy just to run a short script.)  All the scripts are in the default package but they share some common functionality defined in a ".support" package.

I was just reworking it and found an amazingly strange problem--when I use:

```
cd /D c:\scripts
groovyc -d c:\destPath *.groovy
cd support
groovyc -d c:\destPath *.groovy
```

Everything worked fine.

But when I compile the way I'd expect to:

```
groovyc -d c:\destPath c:\scripts\*.groovy
```

It would only compile one of the scripts (I believe it was the last one alphabetically).

Anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: In my ubuntu box it only works if the `-d` param comes last or no script gets compiled

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that I saw somewhere that the -d had to come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems due to the wrapper batch script that executes the `groovyc` executable.

On Windows, the `groovyc` command will start a batch script called `startGroovy.bat`:

```
"%DIRNAME%\startGroovy.bat" "%DIRNAME%" org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler %*
```

I'm no expert in batch files but If you take a close look at `startGroovy.bat`, you can easily notice that there is some kind of a hack that is being done on the `*` wildcard that is passed as an argument to the script (e.g. `c:\scripts\*.groovy`):

```
rem escape minus (-d), quotes (-q), star (-s).
set _ARGS=%*
if not defined _ARGS goto execute
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:-=-d%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:"=-q%
rem Windowz will try to match * with files so we escape it here
rem but it is also a meta char for env var string substitution
rem so it can't be first char here, hack just for common cases.
rem If in doubt use a space or bracket before * if using -e.
set _ARGS=%_ARGS: *= -s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:)*=)-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:0*=0-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:1*=1-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:2*=2-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:3*=3-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:4*=4-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:5*=5-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:6*=6-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:7*=7-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:8*=8-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:9*=9-s%
```

If you turn echoing on by executing `set DEBUG=on` in the command line, and then execute the `groovyc` command again, you will obtain the output of the batch script where you can see how the wildcard is being processed. Below is a sample log with a scenario where we have 3 files named `File1.groovy`, `File2.groovy` and `File3.groovy`.

```
groovyc -d c:\destPath c:\scripts\*.groovy
```

**Sample output:**

```
C:\scripts>set _ARG=C:\scripts\File3.groovy 

C:\scripts>set _ARG=C:\scripts\File3.groovy 

C:\scripts>set _ARG=C:\scripts\File3.groovy 

C:\scripts>set CMD_LINE_ARGS= C:\scripts\File3.groovy 

C:\scripts>set _ARG=
```

It seems the script is ignoring the first two files and eventually only the last one is passed to the `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler` class (the actual compiler). This behavior does not exist when the `*` wildcard is the first character in the path to the source files.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Sounds like a groovy bug with the windows batch integration--I'm surprised I didn't see it reported anywhere.  I don't like digging into those groovy batch files they seem complex and fragile--yet I just assumed I was doing something wrong.  Should know better than to assume.